# How do you fire event using NotifyPSEvent every time a field is changed?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm trying to run event handler methods the moment a Presentation Space is changed. I'm not the most familiar with the native AUTPS methods but the PS.NotifyPSEvents seems promising

I've tried some of the online examples on the IBM sites but i cant seem to figure them out.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public AutPS A_PS = new AutPS();
    public AutOIA A_OI = new AutOIA();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A_PS.SetConnectionByName("A");
        A_OI.SetConnectionByName("A");

        A_PS.NotifyPSEvent += A_PS_NotifyPSEvent();
        A_PS.RegisterPSEvent(true);
    }

    private AutPSTypeLibrary.IPSEvent_NotifyPSEventEventHandler A_PS_NotifyPSEvent()
    {
        if (A_PS.SearchText("GEEP", PsDir.pcSrchForward, 1, 1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BLAH"); return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that when the PS registers a field change, that i could capture this and record what was changed, however it's only firing the event upon starting my program regardless of anything being updated on the screen. Subsequently, when i do update anything on the screen the event does not fire. I'm sure i'm just misunderstanding how this particular method is working, but I've searched for a week with no real answers that i can translate well enough to have it working. Any info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I was on the right track with the events but missed a little bit of information. below is the resolution that worked for me:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A_PS.SetConnectionByName("A");
        A_OI.SetConnectionByName("A");
        //Added a new A_PS_NotifyPSEvent handler and it works perfectly now. 
        A_PS.NotifyPSEvent += A_PS_NotifyPSEvent1; 

        A_PS.RegisterPSEvent(true);
        A_Reco.AddPS(A_PS);
    }

    private void A_PS_NotifyPSEvent1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BLAH");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```